# Inverse of a mathematical statement.

Tags: logic, proof-writing

If the quadrilateral ABCD is a parellelogram with one right angle , then the quadrilateral ABCD is a rectangle.

What is the inverse statement of the above statement?

1. If the quadrilateral ABCD is not a parellelogram with one right angle ,then the quadrilateral ABCD is a rectangle.
2. If the quadrilateral ABCD is a parellelogram with no right angle ,then the quadrilateral ABCD is a rectangle.
3. Both

Comment: By "inverse", do you mean "negation"?  If so, then to negate a statement (A implies B), first write that statement in the form (not A) or B.  Now negate it using DeMorgan's Laws:

not [ (not A) or B ] = A and (not B).

Answer (score 1):

Inverse:

If the quadrilateral $ABCD$ is **not** a parallelogram with one right angle, then the quadrilateral $ABCD$ is **not** a rectangle.

p = the quadrilateral $ABCD$ is a parallelogram with one right angle

q = the quadrilateral $ABCD$ is a rectangle

if $(not)p $ then $(not)q$

Answer (score 1):

Keep these three distinct, but related, notions in mind:

If the original statement is 'If P then Q', then:

The **Inverse** is: 'If not P then not Q'

The **Converse** is: 'if Q then P'

The **Contrapositive** is: 'if not Q then not P'

Note that:

- The Inverse and the Converse are not equivalent, and also not implied by the original.
- The Contrapositive is equivalent (and therefore is implied by, as well as implies, to the original.
- A statements' Inverse is equivalent to its Converse (not the same, but equivalent)
- The Inverse of the Converse of any statement is the Contrapositive of statement. Same for the Converse of the Inverse.